# Inflation of the Universe as Bose Einstein Condensate (Literature)

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, cosmological-inflation, bose-einstein-condensate

I'm searching for literature in the field of cosmological models which use a Bose-Einstein-Condensate (BEC) to model the process of inflation. Especially the analytical results the cubic BEC models are interesting for me.

Additional if you can recommend any papers which do numerics for BEC are of interest too. I also try to understand the relativistic correction of a BEC of a scalar field $\psi$ which dynamic is determined by the Gross-Pitaevskii equation. As far as I know this adapted equation has to be of Klein-Gordon type
\begin{equation}
\left( \Box +m^2 \right) \phi = - \frac{\lambda}{3!} \left( \phi^{+} \phi\right) \phi,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is a suitable constant. So it would be nice if you can recommend some good papers on this to

Comment: Why do think BECs can be used to model inflation?  What's the equation of state of the BEC?